# Difference bwteen UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger and UNCalendarNotificationTrigger?

Tags: ios, usernotifications

My app is very notification dependent and I have recently noticed some notification issues which never used to be there before iOS 11.2.

1) Calling removeDeliveredNotifications on a notification by a UNCalendarNotificationTrigger does not remove it anymore, but it does remove notifications triggered by a UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.
(The fact that removeDeliveredNotifications doesn't work for UNCalendarNotificationTrigger seems very weird)

2) Pressing an action on a notification triggered by a UNCalendarNotificationTrigger results in all of the other notifications triggered with UNCalendarNotificationTrigger's to be removed, but does not remove any UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggered notifications.

Is this behaviour normal or have I missed something maybe in my Xcode project or in my understanding of these two triggers? Please help...

Comment: I am also having similar issue.  Notifications delivered with  `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` are not returned by the API - `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications` function.  It always returns an empty array.  I am particular observing it from iOS 11.2.

Comment: Looks like a bug on Apples side. I’m surprised more people haven’t noticed. I just resorted to using UNTimeIntervalNotificationTriggers.